# Why Oracle does not permit you to create both a primary key and unique constraint with the same columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

Trying to understand Constraints.
This [article](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php) says

> Oracle does not permit you to create both a primary key and unique
>   constraint with the same columns.

Followed by an example:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
( supplier_id numeric(10) NOT NULL,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  contact_name varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT supplier_unique UNIQUE (supplier_id)
);
```

Do I understand correctly that for this query to work the created `supplier_id` **must not** be a primary key?

Also, why is it not allowed? Because Primary Keys are unique by definition and putting a constraint just on that column is meaningless anyway?

Comment: I think I found the answer to my 2nd question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224505/are-there-any-reason-to-use-both-primary-key-and-unique-key-together-on-the-same

Comment: Because it also won't let you create two indexes with the same columns

Comment: Might it also be a factor that a foreign key can be against a PK or unique constraint, so having both would be a bit ambiguous - particularly if you then tried to drop one of them? (The search_condition column for the FK would have to change to point to the other constraint, potentially, and it would have to look for other constraints before dropping too, making everything more complicated...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both primary key and unique constraint create an underlying unique index. And since (most of the time) there's no sense in creating twice the same index, Oracle checks and forbids this.

**Note** about that "most of the time" above: Sometimes it might make sense to have both a B*Tree index and a bitmap index over the same columns. This can be done via function-based indexes, but that's a rather "advanced hack" which comes with a price of making the Oracle query optimizer going slightly nuts about using the "hacked" one.

> Do I understand correctly that for this query to work the created `supplier_id` must not be a primary key?

Yes, in your code example, the `supplier_id` must not be a primary key in order to allow you to create a unique constraint over the `supplier_id`.

Comment: Either constraint can be created against an existing index though, so in principal both could be against the same index?

Comment: so supplier_id in the code example must not be a primary key? (if so, please edit your answer and I'll accept you as the correct answer)

Comment: In your code example you don't have a primary key declaration anyway, but OK, I've edited my answer according to your needs.

Comment: I'm not saying that means it is allowed - it isn't - just that I don't think the inability to create two unique indexes for the same column(s) can be the (only) reason Oracle doesn't allow you to have both constraints, as in theory they could both use the same index anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole, you got me with this one. Yes, you're right, now I finally got myself to trying it - even with a prebuilt unique index, Oracle does not allow for creating unique/primary constraint on a column when there's already some on the column. Fails with `ORA-02261: such unique or primary key already exists in the table`. (A common sense says: Why on Earth would it allow for having both?) Thanks. Answer updated one more time.